# Draggable Listview item on click disable

Tags: android, listview

using the example ,which was a  bit complicated
https://github.com/philcbrown/DraggableListView
 i was trying to disable particular item click/touch when moving to particular pos and checking for particular text,one after another for all listview items,but it was not working,what i tried was using

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();
        Log.d("1", ""+"Item clicklistener");

        if (pos == 0) {
            if (playerChanged == "King")
                Log.d("2", ""+"in isEnabled");
            mDraggableListView.setDragStatus(false);

        } else {
            mDraggableListView.setDragStatus(true);
        }
    }                           
});
```

in the class where listview adapter is set and also

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (position == 1){
        if (text == "King")
            Log.d("3", ""+"in isEnabled");
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

in DraggableGenericAdapter class ,using listview for first time

my getView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    boolean isConverted = true;

    if (view == null) {

        Log.v("talkinginterval", "create view " + position);

        view = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, parent, false);
        isConverted = false;
    }

    modifyView(position, view, isConverted);

    for (int i = 0; i < mTo.length; i++) {

        View v = view.findViewById(mTo[i]);
        String from = mFrom[i];
        String data = mDataProvider.getItem(position);

        String d = data.toString();

        boolean bound = false;
        if (mViewBinder != null) {
            bound = mViewBinder.setViewValue(view, v, d, from);
        }

        if (!bound) {

            if (v instanceof TextView) {

                ((TextView) v).setText(d);

            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a "
                + " view that can be bounds by this Adapter");
            }
        }

    }

    return view;
}
```

and layouts

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:mk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     <View
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#000000" />
     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="960dp"
         android:layout_height="540dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true">
         <com.package.DraggableListView
             android:id="@+id/listView1"
             android:layout_width="894dp"
             android:layout_height="420dp"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

and 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="60dp" >   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your `getView` of `BaseAdapter` and this view's layout.

Comment: getView its same as in link example

Comment: Did your link's sample project have the same question?

Comment: no ,i have added code of getview